# Session does not recognized from browser

Tags: php, session

My giris.php, called ajax and get the url : giris_script.php. And if the username and password is correct, starts the session. My code is below:

```
<?php 
require "config.php";
require "Cgiris.php";
require "security.php";


$username = security($_POST["username"]);
$password = security($_POST["password"]);
$password = md5($password);

$obj = new Giris;
$result = $obj->control($username, $password);
if($result){
    @session_start();
    $_SESSION["admin"]= $username;  
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

And the other pages control the session, but it could not find any session :

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) header("refresh:0;url=404.php");

require "config.php";
require "Cayarlar.php"; 

$obj = new Ayarlar;
$admin = $obj->getAllInfo();
$user = $admin["username"];

if(!isset($_SESSION['admin']) || $_SESSION['admin'] != $user) header("refresh:0;url=404.php");
```

I print the $_SESSION["admin"] to screen, but nothing displayed.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Why are you suppressing errors from `session_start()`?  It might just make sense for you to have `session_start()` at the top of each page, or in config.php if that is included at the top of every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good idea to put

```
 session_start();
```

at the top of your php code.  Don't put it in the conditional statements.   In other words, always start the session before doing anything else.  You can remove it from your (for example)

```
if($result){

    $_SESSION["admin"]= $username;
}
```

Comment: *must always appear at the top of your php code* NO it doesn't have to be at the top! It just has to be before you access the `$_SESSION` array!

Answer (score 0):

because session_start(); is not top of the page. So, it does not set session

```
$obj = new Giris;
$result = $obj->control($username, $password);
if($result){
    @session_start();// This part must be top of the page !!!
    $_SESSION["admin"]= $username;  
}
```

session_start should be top of the page 
for example in your index.php;

```
<?php 
session_start();

// and you can set your session if there was not any problem you will see your session
?>
```